# OPC UA : what does installing an LDS provide?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

Given these 2 installations:

1. A machine with 3 OPC UA servers.
2. A machine with 3 OPC UA servers and a LDS.

What is the difference in functionality? In particular, I would like to know:

- Is the installation of a LDS mandatory?
- What is the practical difference between discovering a server, then connecting to it, and directly connecting to the endpoint of the server without discovery?
- What does installing an LDS enable to do?

(All this, with proper OPC UA specification references where applicable, please)

Comment: (I am using a comment and not an Answer because I cannot provide the spec references at the moment): 1. LDS installation is not mandatory. 2. For the connection itself, doing it through a discovery server means extra steps and is thus slower. 3. The purpose of the LDS is truly the Discovery; most common usage case is simply to give you the list of servers/server endpoints on the host where the LDS runs. For this purpose, it's real use is to help with app configuration, not during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the installation of a LDS mandatory?

No, the installation of an LDS is purely optional. Especially on small / embedded devices you might not even be able to install anything else than the OPC UA server.

> What is the practical difference between discovering a server, then connecting to it, and directly connecting to the endpoint of the server without discovery?

With the LDS running on a standarized port (4840) it is possible to discover all servers on the computer without knowing their endpoint URLs. Without an 
LDS there is no way to connect to a server without knowing the URL.

As already commented, having the LDS makes discovery (very) slightly slower, as a connection to both LDS and server has to be established.

If only one server is running on the computer one might want to set the port of this server to 4840, so clients discovering on the computer find the server without needing to know a custom port.

> What does installing an LDS enable to do?

It simply allows to discover all servers running on the computer without knowing all their different endpoint URLs.

Future versions will contain enhancements, broadcasting this information via Zeroconf, so every LDS would have the list of all OPC UA servers on the local network.